# Why a CNN learns different feature maps

Tags: conv-neural-network

1. I understand (and please correct me if my understanding is wrong) that the primary purpose of a CNN is to reduce the number of parameters from what you would need if you were to use a fully connected NN. And CNN achieves this by extracting "features" of images.
2. CNN can do this because in a natural image, there are small features such as lines and elementary curves that may occur in an "invariant" fashion, and constitute the image much like elementary building blocks.
3. My question is: when we create layers of feature maps, say, 5 of them, and we get these by using the sliding window of a size, say, 5x5 on an image that has pixels of, say, 100x100, Initially, these feature maps are initialized as random number weight matrices, and must progressively adjust the weights with gradient descent right? But then, if we are getting these feature maps by using the exactly same sized windows, sliding in exactly the same ways (sharing the same starting point and the same stride value), on the exactly same image, how can these maps learn different features of the image? Won't they all come out the same, say, a line or a curve?
4. Is it due to the different initial values of the weight matrices? (I.e. some weight matrices are more receptive to learning a certain particular feature than others?)

Thanks!! I wrote my 4 questions/opinions and indexed them, for the ease of addressing them separately!

Comment: 1. I believe its primary prupose its learn filters ad-hoc for the recognition task. At least that is the way that is presented by LeCun in 90s

3. mmm the first convolution will do what you are mention, but then there is as many convolution you want and those are using the output of its previous convolution.